# Laravel 5 - Redirects in Sub-function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a fix to allow a redirect in a sub-function call, instead of in a controller

I've created the following function & call and it works, with the redirect in the controller instead of my sub function call.

Here is my call to the function **checkAccess()**:

```
$access = new \App\Library\Access;
if($access->checkAccess($accessList, 'admin-dashboard', 'r')){
    return view('portal.admin.dashboard');
}else{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Here is my function:

```
public function checkAccess($accessList, $name, $permission){
    return array_filter($accessList, function($element) use($name, $permission){
        if($element->name == $name && $element->permission == $permission){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried replacing the return false; with the redirect and this does not work. It basically just returns true.

Comment: Preferable use the built-in Authorization, it provides tools that you can customize, and the Gate Facade can ease the job, for both Controllers, and View items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a fix to allow a redirect in a sub-function call, instead of in a controller

**Don't.** Your access-checking service should have zero knowledge of the view layer (controllers, views, redirects, etc.). If you've ever heard of concepts such as separation of concerns and the single responsibility principle, that type of blending is exactly what these concepts encourage you to evaluate and separate properly.

Your `Access` class is meant to check for access levels, permissions, etc. It should *not* be meant to generate responses based on those things. That's the controller's job.

Your first code example is perfectly fine, and is what I'd recommend you stick with.

Comment: I've come to this conclusion trying to search out answers as well.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you want something like this

```
public function checkAccess($accessList, $element, $permission){
    if (is_array($accessList)) {
        foreach ($accessList as $access) {
            if ($access->element == $element && $access->permission == $permission) {
                return view('portal.admin.dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

and then, you should `return` the result

```
$access = new \App\Library\Access;
return $access->checkAccess($accessList, 'admin-dashboard', 'r');
```

Concerning the better way of checking if an object list has parameters, maybe you find useful the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function of php.

Comment: The reason I do it the way I do is because that checkAccess will be called not just for page views but items on a given page (buttons, fields, labels). The end goal is to have a checkAccess() and a checkBreach() basically check access will throw back a false and checkBreach will throw back a redirect if not true.